# Jest: Can I have two wrappers to do my tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new in React and I doing some tests on my Toolbar component and a one point I run into the situation that I need to do some stuffs with a shallow wrapper and others with a mount wrapper.
My question is: Is this a good practice to have two wrappers in a test suite? or there's some better options to do that?

```
let shallowWrapper;
let mountWrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
  shallowWrapper = shallow(
    <Router>
      <Toolbar />
    </Router>).dive(styles);
  mountWrapper = mount(
    <Router>
      <Toolbar />
    </Router>);
});
```